# How can i strore javascript variables in session to retrieve in another jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jsp, request

This is my javaScript code where i'm getting student name and saving in session while retrieving in another jsp page its showing null?
'
 `var studentName = document.getElementById("studentName").value;
 '<%Session["studentName"] = "' + studentName + '"; %>';`'

and i'm forwarding that page to next.jsp page as window.location.href="next.jsp" and i'm calling those values as '
`String studentName = request.getParameter("studentName");
out.println(studentName);`'

in the javascript im getting correct value,and in next.jsp page its printing null value,what's mistake i'm doing?

Comment: You might want to use cookies for this data.

Comment: if there is no option i will use cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You have set a session attribute in the first page and your are trying to get its value as if you are getting it from a submitted form.

While setting session in the previous page, use

```
session.setAttribute("session_attributename", studentName)
```

While getting the value in next page, use

```
session.getAttribute("session_attributename");
```

If you submit a form, then only you  can use `request.getParameter("....")` to obtain the value in next page.

```
String studentName = request.getParameter("studentName");
out.println(studentName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var studentName = document.getElementById("studentName").value;
window.location.href="next.jsp?studentName="+studentName;
```

### in next.jsp

```
String studentName = request.getParameter("studentName");
out.println(studentName);
```

In this page you can store the name in session and once stored you can access the session value anywhere by using the session attribute name.

```
session.setAttribute("sname", studentName); (in next.jsp)
```

To get the Student name (in any page)

```
String studentName = (String)session.getAttribute("sname");
```